# How to compare input given by user with integer or string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm unable to compare users input as str or int in following code..

```
A=input(" ") 
if type(A)=str: 
    Print("this is string") 
elif type(A)=int: 
    Print("this is integer")
```

So please tell me how to deal with this type of problem

Comment: `input()` always returns a string.

Comment: A is always a string. You need A.isdigit()

Comment: This is not runnable code. You need `==` for equality comparisons.

Comment: Your question is tagged Python 3 _and_ Python 2. The answer depends on which one it is.

Comment: But how to write this code to run without error

Comment: `if type(A)==str:` not `if type(A)=str:` (the difference is the `==` for comparison instead of `=` for assignment)

Answer (score 0):

use string class isdigit() method to check user input is number or string.